Second-Fix DIY W.C Installation - Water Level - UK
I am fitting my second DIY W.C now. First attempt was a relative's home, second attempt will be my own.
Overall, the W.C will have a sink and toilet pan only. And my question is strictly about the water level.

There will be a resting water level in the cistern.
and a resting water level in the water supply/trap for the sink.
My question is: should the water level of the cistern be below the water level of the sink to ensure optimal drainage?
Or does this matter?

Be good to hear everyone's thoughts, and whether this is the presumption between UK guidance heights.
Thanks in advance

I'm not clear on why you think there might be any relation between the 2 water levels. The level in the cistern is typically controlled by a float valve of some sort, and the water is supplied form your home's main water supply. The water in the sink's trap has nothing to do with any water supply - it's in the drain plumbing, not the supply side.

Hi @brhans. In terms of relations, I am clear that the cistern and sink are controlled by different wastes, and different supply pipes. However, my point is more about the overall water level, and the implications for pressure build ups, sink gargling etc, if there are pressure build ups. There is a vented down pipe, however, I thought I would ask the cistern-sink-level question, nevertheless.
